# Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: C:\xampp1\newlibri\resources\views\book.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

I am building a review system with Laravel. I have a Table Called

> Book Table
>
> User Table
>
> Review Table

In my review table, I have this

```
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('book_id')->nullable();;
        $table->string('headline')->nullable();
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->string('rating')->nullable();
        $table->tinyInteger('approved')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
```

It stores User_Id and Book_id

> In my `BookReview` Model I have this

```
public function books()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Book::class);
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

> In `user` model

```
public function books()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class);
}

public function review()
{
    return $this->hasOne(BookReview::class);
}
```

> In `Book` model

```
public function reviews()
{
    return $this->hasMany(BookReview::class);
}
```

> In my Controller I have this

```
public function show(Book $book, Author $author_id) {

    $data = array();
    $data['relatedBooks'] = Book::where('author_id', $book->author_id)
    ->where('id', '!=', $book->id)
    ->take(5)->get();
    $data['avg'] = BookReview::where('book_id', $book->id)->avg('rating');
    $data['reviews'] = BookReview::where('book_id', $book->id)->get();

    return view('book', compact("data"))->with('book', $book);
 }
```

> In my blade.php

```
    @foreach($data['reviews'] as $review)
    <p>{{ $review->user_id->name }}</p>
    @endforeach
```

But it returned error

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: C:\xampp1\newlibri\resources\views\book.blade.php)

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

### UPDATE

> Book Table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->text('about');
        $table->string('image_url');
        $table->string('epub_url');
        $table->integer('author_id'); 
        $table->string('publisher');  
        $table->year('year');
        $table->boolean('recommended')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();    
    });
}
```

> USER TABLE

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('avatar')->nullable();
        $table->string('password')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();

    });
}
```

> REVIEW TABLE

```
    Schema::create('book_reviews', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('book_id')->nullable();;
        $table->string('headline')->nullable();
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->string('rating')->nullable();
        $table->tinyInteger('approved')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `<?php var_dump($data['review']) ?>` just to see if the `$data['reviews']` is not null?

Comment: I have, it's not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're defining a  `hasMany` relationship between `BookReview` and `User` models via

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

You need to loop through `$review->users` to get each user's review

Fix

```
public function show(Book $book, Author $author_id) {
    //...
    $data['reviews'] = BookReview::with('users')->where('book_id', $book->id)->get();

    return view('book', compact("data"))->with('book', $book);
 }
```

Blade

```
@foreach($data['reviews'] as $review)
  @foreach($review->users as $user)
    <p>{{ $user->name }}</p>
  @endforech
@endforeach
```

**Edit**

Regarding your update you must change `users()` method relationship from `hasMany` to `belongsTo` in your `BookReview` model

BookReview.php

```
//..
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Controller

```
public function show(Book $book, Author $author_id) {

    $data = array();
    $data['relatedBooks'] = Book::where('author_id', $book->author_id)
    ->where('id', '!=', $book->id)
    ->take(5)->get();
    $bookReviews = BookReview::with('user')->where('book_id', $book->id)->get();
    // avoid hitting db twice for the same query
    $data['avg'] = $bookReviews->avg('rating');
    $data['reviews'] = $bookReviews;

    return view('book', compact('data', 'book'));
}
```

Blade

```
@foreach($data['reviews'] as $review)
   <p>{{ $review->user->name }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: It returned this error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.book_review_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`book_review_id` in (6, 7))

Comment: BookReview model represents which table ?

Comment: I think my table is causing the problem, my table name is  `book_reviews`. So I tried to do this     'protected $table = 'book_reviews';'. But its the same.

Comment: could you please add all your involved tables with their schema and full models classes code so we can help

Answer (score 0):

`user_id` is an integer, not an object. You should iterate between the defined relation `$review->users`.

Controller:

```
...
$data['reviews'] = BookReview::where('book_id', $book->id)->with('users')->get();
...
```

View:

```
...
@foreach($review->users as $u)
    <p>{{ $u->name }}</p>
@endforeach
...
```

Comment: It returned this error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.book_review_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`book_review_id` in (6, 7))

Comment: does your `users` table contains the foreign key `book_review_id`?. If not, the relation `users` in your `BookReview` model will not work.

Comment: User table doesn't have book_review_id

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
@foreach($data['reviews'] as $review)
<p>{{ $review->users()->first()->name }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: This loop will execute a query for each review to retrieve the `users`. So, if we have 100 reviews, this loop would run 100 separate queries to retrieve the `users`  of each review.

Comment: Use eager loading instead